# Get Controls inside a Control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

Im developing a WinRT application and have an idea of what I want to do. I want to show a list inside a element of a list on click. So when I click on an item in the first list, a list inside that item will then expand.

```
<ListView x:Name="SectionListView" SelectionChanged="ListSelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/EmbossedEllipse.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NumberOfQuestions}"  />
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <ListView x:Name="SubMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Branches}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I click on an element in "SectionListView" I want the "SubMenu" inside that item to get visible.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a converter to change the state of  the `SubMenu`'s Visibility.

EDIT:
Add a property to know that your item is selected (a boolean).

```
<ListView x:Name="SubMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding Branches}" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The Converter:

```
public sealed class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, can you please give some example?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know how to use the IsSelected. I've googled a bit and tried to find out but with no luck.. 

`Error: BindingExpression path error: 'IsSelected' property not found on 'TillsynApplication.Classes.Checklist, TillsynApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. BindingExpression: Path='IsSelected' DataItem='TillsynApplication.Classes.Checklist, TillsynApplication, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView' (Name='SubMenu'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')`

Comment: Your `CheckList` model needs to have the `IsSelected` property. If you don't want to have this property in your model, use Anton Tykhyy's way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` attached property, it was introduced for just such a purpose. Here's some XAML to get you started (declare a BooleanToVisibilityConverter somewhere if you haven't already done so).

```
<ListView x:Name="SubMenu" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ...
```